# general stochastic integral using Riemann sum

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

How can I compute the general integral integral $\int B_{t}^{m} dB_{t} $ where B is brownian motion or white noise using the Riemann sum? I know how it's done for m=1, 2 and 3 but is there a way to generally compute the Riemann sum limit without resorting to induction

Comment: You can mimick the proof of Itô's formula...  (though I honestly don't see the point.. why do you want to compute the integral using Riemann sums...?)

Comment: I know I could simply use ito's formula but this is what my professor wants  and I can't figure out how to do it this way

Comment: Well, as I said... you can mimick the **proof** of Itô's formula (without using Itô's formula itself).